# PHP - arsort() But number at first place

Tags: php

I have the problem as I described in the title.

I need `arsort` function on my array (I need high to low and keep keys).

But I need Numbers *before* Alphabetic characters.

Example:

```
["5","2","1","D","BC","A"]
```

Standart **arsort()**:

```
["D","BC","A","5","2","1"]
```

I need:

```
["5","2","1","D","BC","A"]
```

I think I will have to use some other fuction than something from standart sort or do it by myself.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Implement your own sorting using `uasort()`.

Comment: In your example, `"5"` is a string.

Comment: yep numbers are represent as string. but i need to sort them as a numbers

Comment: If your numbers are not strings but numbers, arsort() will work.

Comment: but i am saying they are strings :)

Comment: If you really need strings, you can convert, sort and convert back...

Comment: There is an problem with variables. String can be from 1-30char lenght and it can start with few numbers or few alphabetical characters. I dont know how to split Number and Alphabetical string from each other :(

Comment: I wrote a php snippet here: https://3v4l.org/ZF3gI if your keys don't mix numeric and alphabetical keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = array("3", "1", "10","5","A","B","Z","C");
sort($array, SORT_NATURAL);

var_dump($array);

array(8) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "3"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "5"
  [3]=>
  string(2) "10"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "A"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "B"
  [6]=>
  string(1) "C"
  [7]=>
  string(1) "Z"
}
```

---

Sort natural by values preserving keys (descending order):

```
$array = array("10"=>"3", "a"=>"1", 2=>"10","3"=>"5", "1"=>"A","20"=>"B","5"=>"Z","123"=>"C");
natsort($array);
$array = array_reverse($array, true);
var_dump($array);

array(8) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "Z"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "C"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "B"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "A"
  [4]=>
  string(2) "10"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "5"
  [6]=>
  string(1) "3"
  ["a"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

---

It should work unless you want a different sort criteria, then you should explain it better.

```
$array = array(6=>"115-0001 LMH", 7=>"158-0154 FGM", 8=>"116-0115 Korea", 9=>"VG1305154454", 0=>"VGE54815313", "10"=>"3", "a"=>"1", 2=>"10","3"=>"5", "1"=>"A","20"=>"B","5"=>"Z","123"=>"C");
natsort($array);
$array = array_reverse($array, true);
var_dump($array);

array(13) {
  [5]=>
  string(1) "Z"
  [0]=>
  string(11) "VGE54815313"
  [9]=>
  string(12) "VG1305154454"
  [123]=>
  string(1) "C"
  [20]=>
  string(1) "B"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "A"
  [7]=>
  string(12) "158-0154 FGM"
  [8]=>
  string(14) "116-0115 Korea"
  [6]=>
  string(12) "115-0001 LMH"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "10"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "5"
  [10]=>
  string(1) "3"
  ["a"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

Comment: standart sort will break my keys

Comment: So you want to sort by value and preserve keys?

Comment: yep as you said sort by value and keep keys :)

Comment: please add a part of the array with real keys and values that you have

Comment: `natsort()` will arange your array in natural order by value, this means numbers and after letters, if you want it to be descending use `array_reverse()` on the sorted array

Comment: i know i already tried it. but i need numbers from highest then letters.

Comment: here are some real values: 115-0001 LMH
158-0154 FGM
116-0115 Korea
VG1305154454
VGE54815313

Comment: Edited my response, forgot to preserve keys when did `array_reverse()`. The natural order is characterized by ordering numbers first in ascending order and after that the strings in alphabetical order, you want descending so i reversed the array.

Comment: It seems fine on first look, but i wanted numbers on first position. For example : "158-0154 FGM" has to be above "Z" and "1" still above "A"

Comment: You will need a custom function, or if you don't have numeric keys in the array you can use `array_multisort()`, but this will reindex numeric keys...You can find variants of functions using `array_multisort()` that will do the job as you want.

Comment: `function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (is_numeric(substr($a, 0, 1)) && (is_numeric(substr($b, 0, 1)))){
  return ($a < $b) ? 1 : -1;
 }
 if (is_numeric(substr($a, 0, 1)) && (!is_numeric(substr($b, 0, 1)))){
  return -1;
 }
 if (!is_numeric(substr($a, 0, 1)) && (is_numeric(substr($b, 0, 1)))){
  return 1;
 }
 return ($a < $b) ? 1 : -1;
}
uasort($sem, 'cmp');`

Answer (score 1):

As I suggested in the comments, if you keys dont mix numerics and alphabetical chars together, you can convert the numeric keys, short the array, then convert it back :

```
<?php

$array = ["5","2","1","D","BC","A"];

$array2 = [];

foreach($array as $value) {
    if(is_numeric ($value)){
        $array2[] = intval($value);
    } else {
        $array2[] = $value;
    }
}

arsort($array2);

$endArray = [];
foreach($array2 as $value) {
    if(is_int($value)){
        $endArray[] = "$value";
    } else {
        $endArray[] = $value;
    }
}

var_dump($endArray);
```

https://3v4l.org/ZF3gI

Comment: for example "115-0226 XMU_China"

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for Bad answer at first time, now   ***UPDATED ***

```
<?php
$arr = ["1","2","5","D","A","BC"];
$nums = [];
$chars = [];
foreach($arr as $v){
    if(is_numeric($v)){
        $nums[] = $v;
    }else{
        $chars[] = $v;
    }
}
rsort($nums);
arsort($chars);
$output = array_merge($nums, $chars);
print_r($output);
?>
```

Try it in [PhpFiddle.org](http://phpfiddle.org/)

Comment: as i said one comment up, the string are mixed numbers and char i cant use is_numeric :/